# Info window doesn't work in google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I made buttons that each button refer to a location on the map and it works fine, not in good way but it works, **but when I tried to add an info window that will appear on the marker it doesn't work**, I don't know why!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marker animations with <code>setTimeout()</code></title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

      #floating-panel {
        margin-left: -52px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <button id="drop" onclick="drop()">Nasr City</button>
      <button id="drop" onclick="drop1()">Shorouk</button>
      <button id="drop" onclick="drop()">Shubra</button>
      <button id="drop" onclick="drop()">Future University</button>
      <button id="drop" onclick="drop()">Drop Markers</button>

     </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

// If you're adding a number of markers, you may want to drop them on the map
// consecutively rather than all at once. This example shows how to use
// window.setTimeout() to space your markers' animation.

var neighborhoods = [
  {lat: 52.511, lng: 13.447}
];
var neighborhoods1 = [
  {lat: 52.520, lng: 13.410}
];

var markers = [];
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {lat: 52.520, lng: 13.410}
  });
}

function drop() {
  clearMarkers();
  for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
    addMarkerWithTimeout(neighborhoods[i], i * 200);
  }
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

}
function drop1() {
  clearMarkers();
  for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods1.length; i++) {
    addMarkerWithTimeout(neighborhoods1[i], i * 200);
  }
  t
}

function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    }));
  }, timeout);
}

function clearMarkers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
}


 var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
      'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
      'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
      'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
      '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
      'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
      'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
      'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
      'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
      'Heritage Site.</p>'+
      '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
      'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
      '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });



    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC1CJHONRDvyfSS3xAOG9SfW_VCXMoLK5Y&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: uluru is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

you have to add info window to map object

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(window, 'load', infowindow.open(map, marker));
```

Comment: where must i add it ?

Answer (score 0):

This will open the infowindow on a marker:

```
function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(window, 'load', function(evt) {
      infowindow.open(map, marker));
    });
    markers.push(marker);
  }, timeout);
}
```

You have only defined one infowindow with a fixed content, so it will be the same information for each marker.

**code snippet:**

```js
// If you're adding a number of markers, you may want to drop them on the map
// consecutively rather than all at once. This example shows how to use
// window.setTimeout() to space your markers' animation.

var neighborhoods = [{
  lat: 52.511,
  lng: 13.447
}];
var neighborhoods1 = [{
  lat: 52.520,
  lng: 13.410
}];
var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
var markers = [];
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {
      lat: 52.520,
      lng: 13.410
    }
  });
}

function drop() {
  clearMarkers();
  for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
    addMarkerWithTimeout(neighborhoods[i], i * 200);
  }
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

}

function drop1() {
  clearMarkers();
  for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods1.length; i++) {
    addMarkerWithTimeout(neighborhoods1[i], i * 200);
  }
}

function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
      infowindow.open(map, marker)
    })
  }, timeout);
}

function clearMarkers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
}


var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
  '<div id="siteNotice">' +
  '</div>' +
  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>' +
  '<div id="bodyContent">' +
  '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
  'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the ' +
  'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) ' +
  'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km ' +
  '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major ' +
  'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is ' +
  'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the ' +
  'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, ' +
  'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World ' +
  'Heritage Site.</p>' +
  '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">' +
  'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> ' +
  '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>' +
  '</div>' +
  '</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: uluru,
  map: map,
  title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
});
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap)
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
}

#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#floating-panel {
  margin-left: -52px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="floating-panel">
  <button id="drop" onclick="drop()">Nasr City</button>
  <button id="drop" onclick="drop1()">Shorouk</button>
  <button id="drop" onclick="drop()">Shubra</button>
  <button id="drop" onclick="drop()">Future University</button>
  <button id="drop" onclick="drop()">Drop Markers</button>

</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: i tried that all in one page but still no info page open , i put my new code in a comment , please check it , thanks

Comment: it's works fine , but when i try to merge all in one file , it doesn't work , can i know the reason ?

Comment: can u tell me which jquery library i should load or where ? , and is there anything wrong in my new code in the comment ?

Comment: The code posted in your "answer" (which is not an answer or a "comment") [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lvx25huv/1/), it doesn't require any jquery